# way to detect list of changes in ip address in client machine

Tags: networking, network-programming, lan

Ours is a small network consisting of 15 users. We have LAN messenger installed in every machine. Someone is misusing it by using anonymous IP address in their system. We traced the anonymous IP as `192.168.0.155`. Now we want to check each system if they have manually changed their IP to the above address. Does Windows stores IP address change event anywhere? All are static IP within a LAN.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is about network configuration

Answer (score 0):

With some luck, I've got an easy solution for you to retrieve some information about the target. You could try to use the `nbtstat`-command.

Just open a command prompt and type in the following:

```
nbtstat -A 192.168.0.155
```

This will output a bunch of information about the target host, including the `machinename` and `MAC address`.

Here is an example, how the output could look like:

[image: nbtstat output]
<sub>(source: [onlinecomputertips.com](http://www.onlinecomputertips.com/images/nbtstat2.jpg))</sub>

Good luck